# Automate Google Chrome using VBA and Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to manipulate Chrome from the Excel VBE using the Selenium add-in.

- I have included Selenium Type Library in my references.
- I am running Chrome v67.
- I have replaced the Chromedriver.exe file in the Selenium
  Basic directory with the version compatible with Chrome v67 (i.e.
  Chromedriver version 38).

My VBA code:

```
Public Sub seleniumtutorial()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
'bot.AddArgument "--headless"
'bot.AddArgument "--disable-extensions"
bot.Start "chrome", "http://google.com"
bot.Get "/"
bot.TakeScreenshot.SaveAs (ActiveWorkbook.Path + "/screenshot.jpg")
bot.Quit
End Sub
```

I am getting the following error message:

[image]

If I include this line of code there is no error message but then I cannot see the Chrome window:

```
bot.AddArgument "--headless"
```

If I include this line of code, as was suggested on SO answers to a similar question, it doesn't solve the issue.

```
bot.AddArgument "--disable-extensions"
```

Comment: Chris - thank you for this. Much appreciated. You have restored my faith in the SO community ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a VBA perspective you are using the wrong driver class to automate Chrome.  You confirmed the location of ChromeDriver but it is completely ignored in your code.

Replace `WebDriver` with `ChromeDriver` in this line:  `Dim bot As New WebDriver`

Or use: `Dim bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver`

That's problem #1.  Problem #2 is the error message you are getting.  You should be getting a run-time error when you use WebDriver not a policy warning.

Not enough information provided to solve problem #2 and it may not have anything to do with VBA.  Given the error message, you may want to have a chat with your admin.